# Evento Keypress não funciona após requisição $.get()

Tags: jquery, dom, get

Estou a desenvolver um sistema em php e estou utilizando o `Jquery` para requisições Client Side.
Tenho uma rotina simples para tratamento de inputs que não permite que o usuário digite um caractere não numérico. 
O script segue:

```
$('.only-numeric').on('keypress',function(event) {
        var tecla = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : event.which;
        if ((tecla > 47 && tecla < 58 || tecla == 0 || tecla == 44)) return true;
        else {
            if (tecla != 8) return false;
            else return true;
        }
    });
```

O mesmo é funcional, porém o problema ocorre quando preciso trabalhar dinamicamente.
Tenho um `select` qua ao alterá-lo, atualizo uma div chamada `characteristic_item`, populando com os novos inputs através do método `$.get()`. E com método `html()` apresento em tela os novos valores.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Tela com os campos atualizados]

```
/**
     * Altera as caracteristicas do imóvel pela categoria do imóvel
     */
    $('#id_category').on('change',function (){

        var cat = $(this).val();
        var id = $('#id_immobile').val();
        var url = url_base + '/Imovel/lista_caracteristicas/' + cat + '/' + id;

        $('#characteristic').show();

        $.get(url,function (retorno) {

            if(retorno) {

                $('#characteristic_item').html(retorno);
            } else {
                $('#characteristic').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Acontece que atualizar os valores da DIV, o meu script que não aceita campos não numéricos não funciona mais.
Fiz o uso do seletor `.on()`, porém não tive sucesso.

**HTML do projeto:**

```
 <select class="full-width" data-init-plugin="select2" name="id_category" id="id_category" required>
   <option></option>
</select>

<input type='text' class='form-control only-numeric' name='convenient' id='checkbox' maxlength='3' value=''>
```

Alguma sugestão de como resolver este caso?

Comment: porque é que, em vez de alterar a `div` nao recebe apenas os novos valores do select e adiciona-os, assim sendo, nunca altera o `select` e todos os eventos continuaram a funcionar... por exemplo: `$("#id_category option").clear(); retorno.forEach(x=>$("#id_category").append("<option>"+x+"</option>")`

Comment: @balexandre o que é alterado não é os options do select. O select me retorna o ID da categoria que por sua vez popula a div que retorna as características do imóvel. Postei a imagem para facilitar. Veja select categoria alimenta os cômodos(características) que está na div `#characteristic > #characteristic_item`

Comment: lamento, mas da maneira como tem a pergunta, não dá para entender o relacionamento... acredito que veja que é facil uma vez que está programando tudo, mas "deste lado" não dá... o codigo que tem em HTML nao tem qualquer `characteristic` ou `characteristic_item` para podermos relacionar os blocos

Comment: @balexandre Ok, vou reformular a dúvida e incluir os blocos faltantes.

Comment: tente criar no Fiddle, JsBin, CodePen, etc um pequeno exemplo que possa reproduzir o que está falhando... até pode ser que encontre o problema ao fazer isso 

Comment: Basta trocar `$('.only-numeric').on('keypress',function(event) {` por `$('body').on('keypress', '.only-numeric', function(event) {` que vai monitorar o keypress mesmo que sejam incluídos novos elementos com a classe `only-numeric` na página dinamicamente.

Comment: @Benilson perfeito, agora eu entendi o comportamento. Eu achava que apenas usando o `on()` no evento keypress que ele já seria incluído ao `DOM` dinamicamente. Problema resolvido e entendido. :)

Comment: Olá, realmente temos problemas em requisições Ajax que adicionam elementos no DOM. 

Uma forma paliativa de resolver seu problema, seria você recarregar a tela como um todo. Assim os eventos para os novos elementos seriam registrados. 

O que você poderia fazer tb é adicionar um evento onchange para essa classe e não permitir que o usuário coloque caracteres não numéricos.

Não sei em que pé vc está no desenvolvimento dessa aplicação, mas recomendo fortemente vc utilizar alguma biblioteca como Angular React ou Vuejs.

Comment: @Benilson adicione uma resposta com a sua solução, para o autor poder a escolher e lhe bonificar

Answer (score 1):

Você está criando novos campos na tela, mas o seu javascript já foi carregado e ele não vai identificar os novos elementos. Como não sei como está seu arquivo, segue o que você pode fazer.

Sugestão 1:
Colocar o código direto no input que está sendo criado: `<input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">`

Sugestão 2:
1. Empacote seu script de "permitir apenas numéricos" em uma função.

```
function minhaFuncao(){
   $('.only-numeric').on('keypress',function(event) {
        var tecla = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : event.which;
        if ((tecla > 47 && tecla < 58 || tecla == 0 || tecla == 44)) return true;
        else {
            if (tecla != 8) return false;
            else return true;
        }
    });
}
```

2. Chame esse script toda vez que atualizar a tela:

```
//....código pra cima
if(retorno) {

                $('#characteristic_item').html(retorno);

                //Aqui vai a função
                minhaFuncao();

            } else {
                $('#characteristic').hide();
            }
//....código pra baixo
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu já tinha feito dessa forma, mas estava insatisfeito por que sabia que tinha uma forma melhor de fazer isso. De todo modo obrigado.
A resposta do @Benilson esclareceu e resolveu o meu problema.